# Increase concurance of scrapy for different domains?

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to configure `scrapy` to follow external links.

At the same time, I have `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3`, so it is polite to the servers.

Is there a way to configure `scrapy` to start downloading external links immediately and in parallel?

From the logs it looks like the external links are sitting in the same queue as the internal links.

My spider is:

```
 16 class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 17     name = "reddit"
 18     start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/']
 19
 20     def parse(self, response):
 21         digest = hashlib.md5(response.body).hexdigest()
 22         if pages.find_one({'digest': digest}):
 23             return
 24         links = LinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
 25         urls = [l.url for l in links]
 26         pages.insert_one({
 27             'digest': digest,
 28             'url': response.url,
 29             'links': urls,
 30             'body': response.text
 31         })
 32         for url in urls:
 33             yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, scrapy usually scrapes pages in parallel. There are these settings that you can modify / override in your scrapy project's settings.py:

- CONCURRENT_REQUESTS
- CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN

(see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests)

**Recommended values:**

While CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN should be set to value not too high to be polite to servers (e.g. low single digit), CONCURRENT_REQUESTS should be as high as possible (without running out of memory) ... so a value of over 100 is recommended here.

Unfortunately the queuing in scrapy is not perfect: for example, if you have more than CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to the same domain (e.g. reddit) **and** these requests are all in the top spots of scrapy's queue, then these requests will block these spots for requests to other domains.

As a consequence only CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN will be processed for a while.

This changes once enough of the reddit requests have been processed and requests to other domains enter the top spots of the scrapy queue. Then - under ideal conditions (e.g. a perfect mix of domains in the request) - the scraper will be able to do CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.

So having a CONCURRENT_REQUESTS value that's as high as possible is key here.

**Also** mixing your requests a bit helps to get around above situation where a big number of requests to the same domain keeps other requests from being processed in parallel. So for example you can assign random priorities to all requests and/or assign higher priorities to external urls.